# How to avoid useMemo overusing?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) the following is stated:

> useMemo will only recompute the memoized value when one of the
>   dependencies has changed. This optimization helps to avoid expensive
>   calculations on every render.

Sounds nice, isn't it? But to optimize performance one needs to be sure the calculations are more expensive than useMemo itself before using it. Are there any suggestions to when to avoid useMemo?

Comment: It's difficult to give an answer for every situation, and it's primarily opinion based, but I personally would not default to `useMemo` and only use it when I know a certain component is very heavy to render. The best thing you can do is to profile your app if needed.

Comment: It's simple - don't use it until it's truly necessary. From the docs: `Write your code so that it still works without useMemo — and then add it to optimize performance.`

Comment: @PavelYe which docs?

Answer (score 1):

Use memo only when rendering a component is expensive